# Connecting Lambda to Neptune DB CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to connect a nodeJS lambda to a Neptune serverless instance. I can't get this to work. I've tried just about everything I can think of but the connection always times out. I'm wondering if I'm just completely missing how to connect these two resources. If I can't use a Neptune serverless instance I'm fine using an instance but even that I've not been able to get a connection with.

Any support with this would be greatly appreciated. I've included my CDK stake with a fake Neptune url.

Thank you in advance for any support you can offer.

```
import {
    aws_lambda as lambda,
    aws_iam  as iam,
} from "aws-cdk-lib";
        const neptuneUrl = "example-db.cluster-cr41xkpkzbr6.eu-west-2.neptune.amazonaws.com";

        const graphDBRole = new iam.Role(this, `${app}-graph-role`, {
            assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
            managedPolicies: [
                iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('NeptuneFullAccess'),
                iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('CloudWatchLogsFullAccess'),
            ]
        });
    enter code here

const feedbackLambda = new lambdaNodejs.NodejsFunction(
            this,
            `${app}-feedback`,
            {
                runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
                entry: path.join(__dirname, `../lambdas/feedback/index.ts`),
                handler: "index.handler",
                timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(60),
                role: graphDBRole,
                environment: {
                    REGION: cdk.Stack.of(this).region,
                    ENVIRONMENT: props.environment,
                    MAIN_GRAPH_DB: neptuneUrl,
                },
            }
        );
```

Comment: I notice that the Lambda function is not running in a VPC.  Neptune is only accessible within the VPC from which it is hosted.

Comment: You're right, that's an issue. I think I need to add private subnets to the lambda too? I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You need to supply the `vpc` and `vpcSubnets` parameters for your function.  As noted in the docs here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Function.html. Both of those parameters should be the same as the VPC and subnets used by your Neptune cluster.